# How can I get emacs (using TRAMP) to edit/save a file on a WebDAV share?

Tags: emacs, webdav, tramp

So I've got a WebDAV share on a virtual machine that I'm running on my laptop.  I want to connect to it via emacs, edit a file, then save it.  Unfortunately, TRAMP keeps giving me an error whenever I try to connect to the file.  The error is "Host #blah# looks like a remote host, `dav' can only use the local host".  The connection string (only lightly anonymized) I'm using is "/dav:10.0.6.12#8000:/folder/another/weeee/doc.txt".

Comment: Can you not just mount it locally? Then you wouldn't even have to use TRAMP.

Comment: Yeah, it's mounted locally through Windows, but it's freaking slow.  I was hoping that there was a speedier plug-in to emacs that would let me work with files over WebDAV.  I really shouldn't have specified TRAMP, because I'll take just about anything.  I've tried using eldav (after compiling nd under Cygwin), but whenever I try to open a file in emacs (using the ":http ://share/folder/file.blah" syntax eldav recognizes), nd throws up, drops a stacktrace (which has almost no useful information), then dies, leaving emacs with a buffer showing that an error occurred.  Very frustrating.